# How Can I set Fragment's data, In MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

My code has 5 fragment with `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. When the code start, a function which name is "UIstart" initializes UI. And that function has

```
Boolean ValDate = homeFrag.ValidDate();
```

`ValidDate()` is in `HomeFragment` which is first page at `ViewPager`. `ValidDate()` set data in text or button. But when `ValidDate()` called in UIstart, I got null object error.

How do I fix code? Here is apart of code.

This is MainActivity

```
private void UIstart(){

    Log.d(TAG, "UIstart: start");

    NavigatorUI = Navigator.HOME;



    ValDate = homeFrag.ValidDate();

    ....

   }
```

And this is HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public String Valid_Date_from;
    public String Valid_Date_to;
    public String[] month = {
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr",
            "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
            "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gatt_services_characteristics, container, false);

        ValidDate();

        return view;

        } 


        public boolean ValidDate(){

        logD(TAG, "ValidDate() Called");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        String dateToString , timeToString ;

        dateToString = String.format("%04d%02d%02d", cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


        timeToString = String.format("%02d%02d", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        int []weeks2 = {R.drawable.date_sun,R.drawable.date_mon,
                R.drawable.date_tue,R.drawable.date_wed,R.drawable.date_thur,
                R.drawable.date_fri,R.drawable.date_sat};

        String valdatefrom = Valid_Date_from;
        Calendar c2= Calendar.getInstance();

        c2.set(parseInt(valdatefrom.substring(0, 4))
                , parseInt(valdatefrom.substring(4, 6)) - 1
                , parseInt(valdatefrom.substring(6, 8)));

        String valdateto = Valid_Date_to;
        Calendar c1= Calendar.getInstance();

        c1.set(parseInt(valdateto.substring(0, 4))
                , parseInt(valdateto.substring(4, 6)) - 1
                , parseInt(valdateto.substring(6, 8)));

        Button Valfrom = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Val_From_Button); // this code occur null object error
        Button Valto = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Val_To_Button);
        TextView Valmonthfrom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Val_Month_From);
        TextView Valmonthto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Val_Month_To);
        TextView Valyearfrom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Val_Year_From);
        TextView Valyearto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Val_Year_To);
        TextView Valtimefrom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Val_Time_From);
        TextView Valtimeto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Val_Time_To);
        TextView  valto_center = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.valto_center);
        FrameLayout ExpireLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Expire_Frame);

        ....

        }
```

Comment: `view` in your validate method , where is it defined in the scope?

Comment: @AbdulKawee I'm sorry but I can't understand what does "define" means.

Comment: can you paste your error log here

Comment: @AbdulKawee   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                         at passtech.mobilelocker.Fragment.HomeFragment.ValidDate(HomeFragment.java:169)

Comment: it clearly says that `view` in `validate()` method is null

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the fragments into viewpager?

Comment: @AbhayBohra well... how can I post my code....? I'm new in stack overflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before returning `view`, you are trying to invoke `ValidDate()` method. `onCreateView()` return the `view`, based on that `view.findViewById()` will be able to bind the controls. In your case, you haven't returned the `view`, hence `NPE`.

Try to call `ValidDate()` method inside `onViewCreated()`.

As Abdul mentioned in comment `ValDate = homeFrag.ValidDate();` is not required.

Comment: well i think he is doing something much more bad , like trying to call the method outside of the fragment which is using view ` ValDate = homeFrag.ValidDate();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call  `homeFrag.ValidDate()` method after the ViewPager adapter has been initialised, so probably do `UiStart` in your activities `onCreate()` method and also initialise viewpager adapter in `onCreate()` then override `onPostCreated()` and call `homeFrag.ValidDate()`